# Iterate over VBA Dictionaries?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the Dictionary class in the MS Runtime Scripting library to store where labels are going to go for a report template. Is there a way to iterate over all the key value pairs in that dictionary like in Python?

I just want to use the key as the row number (It's all going in column A) and the value will be the label header.

Something like:

```
For Each key in dict
    Range("A" & key).Value = dict(key)
Next key
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Try:

```
For Each varKey In oDic.Keys()
    Range("A" & varKey).Value = oDic(varKey)
Next
```

Note that the key iterator must be declared as a `Variant`.

Comment: I would add that strKey should be declared `As Variant`, because the `For Each` doesn't work with `String`s.

Comment: Side note, dictionary keys are returned as an array, so iterating them should be done with a `For...Next` loop for best performance; _do_ use `For Each...Next` when iterating object collections tough.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot out there for this but, if you have multiple values per key, such as in an array, you'll need a bit more code.  This is my first time responding to a post here so apologies if I'm doing something wrong...

```
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim k As Variant
    Dim v As Variant

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    'Add code to populate your dictionary

    For Each k In dict.Keys()
        Debug.Print k, Join(dict(k), ",") 'Prints out all the details for the key
        For Each v In dict(k)
            Debug.Print v
        Next
    Next k
```

Part of this code comes from this post: [VBA Dictionary with Dynamic Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390638/vba-dictionary-with-dynamic-arrays)