# Create a dictionary that has other dictionaries as values

Tags: excel, vba

The structure I want to create

DictionaryMain
-> Dictionary1, Dictionary2, ...
-> Array1Dict1, Array2Dict1, Array1Dict2, Array2Dict2, ...

```vb
Dim Range1 As Range
Set Range1 = Range("O2:O230")
Dim Range2 As Range
Set Range2 = Range("P2:P230")
Dim Range3 As Range
Set Range3 = Range("A2:N800")
SelectedValue = Range("Q2").Value
Dim DictMain As Object
Set DictMain = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
i = 1
For Each Row In Range1.Rows
    If Not IsEmpty(Row.Cells(1).Value) Then
        If Not DictMain.Exists(Row.Cells(1).Value) Then
            Dim dict
            Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dict.Add Range2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, Array(i, 0, "", SelectedValue, 100)
            DictMain.Add Row.Cells(1).Value, dict
            i = i + 1
        Else
            DictMain(Row.Cells(1).Value).Add Range2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, Array(i, 0, "", SelectedValue, 100)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Else: Exit For
    End If
Next Row
For Each Key In DictMain.Keys()
    For Each Row In Range3.Rows
        If Not IsEmpty(Row.Cells(11).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Row.Cells(13).Value) Then
            If Row.Cells(11).Value = Row.Cells(13).Value Then
            Else
                If Not DictMain(Key).Exists(Row.Cells(11).Value) Then
                    DictMain(Key).Add Row.Cells(11).Value, Array(DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(13).Value)(0), Row.Cells(14).Value, Row.Cells(13).Value, 0, 0)
                    val1 = DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(13).Value)(3)
                    val2 = DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(13).Value)(4)
                    val1 = val1 + DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(11).Value)(1)
                    DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(11).Value)(3) = DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(11).Value)(1)
                    DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(11).Value)(4) = val2
                    DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(13).Value)(3) = val1
                    val1 = DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(11).Value)(3)
                    val2 = DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(11).Value)(4)
                    val2 = SelectedValue * val1 / val2
                    val1 = SelectedValue
                    DictMain(Key).Item(Row.Cells(11).Value)(3) = val1
                    DictMain(Key)(Row.Cells(11).Value)(4) = val2
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Else: Exit For
        End If
    Next Row
Next Key
```

I get

> Runtime-Error 424: Object Required

The error occurs at the line

```
val2 = SelectedValue * val1 / val2
```

`val2` and `val1` are both 0.

DictMain has only Variant/String entries.

Comment: Would help to include all of your variable declarations.

Comment: The error 424 does not fit to the line you describe - there is no object used in that line. But it's hard to help you as we don't have your data. Personal advice: Use intermediate variables and maybe an custom class instead of an array - but that's a matter of code review, not SO.

Comment: Why don't you describe in a few sentences what you're trying to do? Never mind the way you're trying to do it at this moment. I can see you have a dictionary with keys. Each item holds another dictionary with keys whose items hold a 5-element array where only the first element is different. The issue here is that you cannot update this array in the way you're trying to do it. Briefly explain what the remaining 4 (same) values should hold. Share the information by editing your post.

Comment: As @VBasic2008 alludes to you cannot directly update an array which is stored as the value of a dictionary key.   You need to do something like: `tmp = myDict(k): tmp(0)=tmp(0)+1: myDict(k) = tmp`  See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26390929/478884

Comment: @FunThomas, sorry, I meant the debugger brings me to that line.

Comment: Thank you Tim Williams and @VBasic2008 I had to copy the array to a new variable, change it, and pass it back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but suggest something like this to avoid the problem of trying to update arrays while they're stored in a dictionary:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim arr, arrData, ws As Worksheet, DictMain As Object, r As Long
    Dim vO, vP, key, vK, vM, dictSub As Object, i As Long, vMArr, vKArr
    Dim SelectedValue, val1, val2
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet   'always be explicit about what sheet you're working with
    'more efficient to read a whole range in one shot
    arr = ws.Range("O2:P230").Value 
    arrData = ws.Range("A2:N800")
    
    Set DictMain = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
        vO = arr(r, 1)
        vP = arr(r, 2)
        If Len(vO) > 0 Then
            i = i + 1
            If Not DictMain.Exists(vO) Then DictMain.Add vO, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            DictMain(vO).Add vP, Array(i, 0, "", SelectedValue, 100)
        End If
    Next r
    
    For Each key In DictMain.Keys()
        Set dictSub = DictMain(key) 'reference the sub-dictionary
        For r = 1 To UBound(arrData)
            vK = arrData(r, 11) 'ColK value
            vM = arrData(r, 13) 'ColM value
            'perform some checks
            If Len(vK) = 0 Or Len(vM) = 0 Or vK = vM Then Exit For
            If dictSub.Exists(vK) Then Exit For
            
            vMArr = dictSub(vM)  'pull out the array
            vKArr = Array(vMArr(0), arrData(r, 14), vM, 0, 0) 'don't add the new one yet....
            
            val1 = vMArr(3)
            val2 = vMArr(4)
            val1 = val1 + vKArr(1)
            vKArr(3) = vKArr(1)
            vKArr(4) = val2
            
            vMArr(3) = val1
            
            val1 = vKArr(3)
            val2 = vKArr(4)
            val2 = SelectedValue * val1 / val2
            val1 = SelectedValue
            vKArr(3) = val1
            vKArr(4) = val2
            
            dictSub.Add vK, vKArr 'add the new key and array array
            dictSub(vM) = vMArr   'return updated array
        Next r
    Next key

End Sub
```