# VBA Find a value in a "column" of a 2D array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I was previously dynamically building a 1D array by looping down a column in a spreadsheet. Because I only wanted unique values in this array, I'm calling

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean.
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

on each element before adding it. So far, so good.

Now I need to have elements from 2 columns stored, so I need to expand this to a 2D array. I only need the original data element to be unique, but my original function will not accept a 2D array.

**Is there a way to search just one "column" of a 2D array to see if a string exists?**

I've thought of a few workarounds, including concatenating both values and keeping them in a 1D array, then parsing them out, etc, but I'd like to know if the "find if one element is unique" approach is possible.

Comment: Array(0,0) would be A1, Array(0,1) would be B1. when you loop just make sure to ref the 2nd part of the array as a constant e.g. column ref, and increment the first part e.g. the row

Comment: Are the values being stored from your second column basically the corresponding values to the values you stored from your first column.  For example will your values basically be: `A1:B1`, `A4:B4`, `A9:B9` ?  Also can you post your looping function?

Comment: Your best bet is to scrap using arrays and to use the `dictionary` data type instead.  It will be much faster for retrieving the data from it.  Here's how to get started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure

Comment: You could use the Dictionary Object.  The Key would determine the unique element and the two columns could be stored in the Item separated by a delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dean MacGregor and Jason_Walker for the comments. I hadn't used dictionaries before, and they were exactly what was called for here. The following two questions got me where I needed to go.

If either of you wants to post a separate answer here, I'm happy to delete this and accept yours.

[Does VBA have Dictionary Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)

[Iterate over VBA Dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296225/iterate-over-vba-dictionaries)

Answer (score 2):

This simple code will help you find string in 1D or 2D arrays. 
Check out how is numbered column index in your code, maybe `If i = ColumnToCheck Then` need little improve

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant, Optional ColumnToCheck As Integer = 1) As Boolean

For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) 'columns
    If i = ColumnToCheck Then
        For j = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) 'rows
            If arr(j, ColumnToCheck) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work, providing you pass it a 2 or more column array

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound1 As String,stringToBeFound2 As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Found1 = 0
    Found2 = 0
    for x=0 to ubound(arr)
        if stringToBeFound1 = arr(x,0) then
            'found
            Found1=1
        end if
        if stringToBeFound2 = arr(x,1) then
            'found
            Found2=1
        end if
        if Found1 =1 and Found2 =1 then IsInArray = TRUE
    next        

End Function
```