# VBA arrays with side-by-side values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Is there a way to define and write an array in VBA such that value pairs are shown two to a line?

```
fndList = Array _
( _
    "PS4",  "PlayStation 4" _
    "WIN",  "Microsoft Windows", _
    "SNES", "Super Nintendo Entertainment System" _
)
```

Something like the above? Using two separate arrays is fine too, thanks.

Comment: Why not test it? If you put a comma immediately after `"PlayStation 4"` then what you have above is perfectly valid VBA. Your actual data seems like it would most naturally fit in a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a comma. Are you trying to create a `fndList(1 to 3, 1 to 2)` array?

Comment: The missing comma was indeed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is (after the missing comma is inserted after `"PlayStation 4"`) perfectly valid VBA. However, it creates a 1-dimensional array. If you want similar notation to create a 2-dimensional array, you can create a custom function:

```
Function Matrix(m As Long, n As Long, ParamArray items()) As Variant
    'Creates an mxn matrix where the items() are filled in by row
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ReDim A(1 To m, 1 To n)
        For i = 1 To m
            For j = 1 To n
                A(i, j) = items(n * (i - 1) + j - 1)
            Next j
        Next i
    Matrix = A
End Function
```

Used like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim fndList As Variant
    fndList = Matrix _
    (3, 2, _
        "PS4", "PlayStation 4", _
        "WIN", "Microsoft Windows", _
        "SNES", "Super Nintendo Entertainment System" _
    )
    Range("A1:B3").Value = fndList
End Sub
```

The array which is created is 1-based rather than 0-based since in Excel VBA 1-based is the default for interacting with ranges. It would obviously be easy enough to tweak the function so that the array returned is 0-based.

Looking a bit more at your actual problem, if your goal is to lookup values like `"Microsoft Windows"` from keys like `"WIN"` then you can use a [Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/915317/4996248):

```
Sub test2()
    Dim fndList As Object
    Set fndList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    fndList.Add "PS4", "PlayStation 4"
    fndList.Add "WIN", "Microsoft Windows"
    fndList.Add "SNES", "Super Nintendo Entertainment System"
    Debug.Print fndList("WIN") 'prints "Microsoft Windows"
End Sub
```

You could modify the `Matrix()` function so that it returns such a dictionary. For example, something like this:

```
Function Dict(ParamArray pairs()) As Object
    'returns a dictionairy where successive pairs of
    'items in the pairs array are treated as key-value
    'pairs. It is assumed than an even number of items
    'are passed
    Dim D As Object
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    n = (UBound(pairs) - 1) / 2
    For i = 0 To n
        D.Add pairs(2 * i), pairs(2 * i + 1)
    Next i
    Set Dict = D
End Function
```

Which can be used like:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim fndList As Object
    Set fndList = Dict _
    ( _
        "PS4", "PlayStation 4", _
        "WIN", "Microsoft Windows", _
        "SNES", "Super Nintendo Entertainment System" _
    )
    Debug.Print fndList("WIN") 'prints "Microsoft Windows"
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I iterate through a Dictionary?

Comment: @posfan12 You can use a `for-each` loop as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296225/4996248 .Note that the loop index should be a variant. This is a nice tutorial on dictionaries: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/ . If you want to go this route, hopefully the function I added in the last edit will be helpful.